# NAudio conversion artifacts

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm capturing IEEE, 48khz, 32 bit audio and attempting to convert it to PCM, 44.1khz, 16 bit audio.  I hear a small pop many times a second in the PCM encoded result.

I've listened to playback of the original audio (the 48khz format.)  It doesn't have artifacts, sounds good.

That leaves the resampling.  Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my conversion code:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 10];

    //wave format is IEEE 48khz, 32 bit
    public byte[] Convert(byte[] input, int length, WaveFormat format)
    {
        if (length == 0)
            return new byte[0];

        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(input, 0, length))
        {
            using (var inputStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(memStream, format))
            {
                //convert bytes to floats for operations.
                WaveToSampleProvider sampleStream = new WaveToSampleProvider(inputStream);

                //resample to 44.1khz
                var resamplingProvider = new WdlResamplingSampleProvider(sampleStream, 44100);

                //convert float stream to PCM 16 bit.
                var ieeeToPCM = new SampleToWaveProvider16(resamplingProvider);
                return readStream(ieeeToPCM);
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] readStream(IWaveProvider waveStream)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = waveStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling `Convert` on small pieces and then concatenating the results?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing. Shoot. That's exactly what's wrong too. You think it'd work if I streamed the conversion, that way the other sampling algorithms can maintain state?

Comment: That should work, that's what it meant for

Comment: @harold just implemented this, using your advice.  Works perfect.  If you want to post an answer I'll accept.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison please post the solution as an answer and mark it answered